# I get No Widget error if I don't do Navigator.of(context).pop() before stripe's presentPaymentSheet

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments, bottom-sheet

I created a bottomSheet that I close if you click on a butom. except for stripe if I do Navigator.of(context).pop() to close the bottomsheet before stripe's presentPaymentSheet and if I finish filling out the stripe form presentPaymentSheet the context is no longer active to navigate to a new route.

```
      // 1. create payment intent on the server
      final response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(
              'https://stripe//'),
          body: {
            'email': email,
            'amount': amount.toString(),
          });

      final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
      //log(jsonResponse.toString());

      //2. initialize the payment sheet
      await stripe.Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
        paymentSheetParameters: stripe.SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
          // Enable custom flow
          customFlow: true,
          // Main params
          paymentIntentClientSecret: jsonResponse['paymentIntent'],
          merchantDisplayName: 'GamRelay',
          // Customer keys
          customerId: jsonResponse['customer'],
          customerEphemeralKeySecret: jsonResponse['ephemeralKey'],
          // Extra options
          //applePay: true,
          //googlePay: true,
          style: ThemeMode.dark,
          //testEnv: true,
          //merchantCountryCode: 'SG',
        ),
      );


      Navigator.of(context).pop(); 

      await stripe.Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();


      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MainScreen()),
          (Route<dynamic> route) => false);

      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => ShippingConfirmation()));
```

the image below is the bottomsheet that I try to close if we click on the buttom of strip

[image]

The image below is the error I receive after completing and submitting the stripe form

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you call the bottomsheet with showModalBottomsheet. As you can see here:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html

the return value is a future, which means you can wait for this call with await. Await on it and call your navigation afterwards.

Your error occurs because the bottomsheet is already closed and so your context is invalid on the 2 pop.

Comment: yes the bottomsheet is already closed. but I need the context to navigate to a new page. but the context show me no widget as error

Comment: Don't use the context of the bottomSheet, use the context of your build method

Comment: I use another context and It working now. Thanks